# Stop launching activity again and again if beacon is in 1 meter

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I have two beacons and when this first beacon comes within 1 meter i fired first activity and when second beacon comes within 1 meter i fired second activity.

Now what i want is if first activity is fired once then application should not launch first activity again  but the problem is that if i press back button from first activity then first activity again get launched if first beacon is in 1 meter and i am facing same problem for second beacon

My manifest file code is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.altbeacon.beaconreference"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.MyApplicationName">

    <activity
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"  
            android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"  
            android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.SECONDACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My application class code is :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = ".MyApplicationName";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BeaconManager  mBeaconManager;
    private Region region;
    private Region mAllBeaconsRegion;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver mBackgroundPowerSaver;
    private RegionBootstrap mRegionBootstrap;
    private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "XYZ";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {    

        mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region("all beacons",null, null, null);     
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);             
        mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, mAllBeaconsRegion);      
        // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
        // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
        // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
        // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb
        //        
        Log.d(TAG, " region.  starting ranging");        
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));        
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(11000l);        
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);

    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {

        //mRegionBootstrap.disable();
        try {
            //mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mAllBeaconsRegion);

            mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
        //Toast.makeText(this, "didEnterRegion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "didEnterRegion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
        // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
        // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.  

    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

        //mRegionBootstrap.disable();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (beacons.size() > 0) {        
            for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {          
                String beconid=beacon.toString();               

                if(beacon.getDistance()<1 && beconid.equals("id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 20155 id3: 28577"))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
                    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                      this.startActivity(intent);                     
                } 

                if(beacon.getDistance()<1 && beconid.equals("id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 8128 id3: 59794"))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                      this.startActivity(intent);                     
                } 

            }

        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: check if it's actually not opening a lot of activities and when you press back there is already another in the background. (depends on the fequancy the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method is called)

Answer (score 0):

You should stop looking for beacons after find one and only restart looking after a certain delay or you could save the ID of the last beacon found and ignore that beacon for a while or until it's out of range.

You can ignore a beacon for 60 seconds with something like this:

```
private String lastBeaconId = "";
private long lastTimeFound = 0;

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

    //mRegionBootstrap.disable();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    if (beacons.size() > 0) {        
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {          
            String beconid=beacon.toString();               

            if (beconid.equals(lastBeaconId)){

                long diff = new Date().getTime();
                //ignore this beacon if it was found 60 seconds ago
                if(diff - lastTimeFound >= 60*1000){ 
                    continue;
                }

            }


            if(beacon.getDistance()<1 && beconid.equals("id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 20155 id3: 28577"))
            {
                //save this beacon
                lastTimeFound = new Date().getTime();
                lastBeaconId = beconid;

                Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
                // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  this.startActivity(intent);                     
            } 

            if(beacon.getDistance()<1 && beconid.equals("id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 8128 id3: 59794"))
            {
                //save this beacon
                lastTimeFound = new Date().getTime();
                lastBeaconId = beconid;

                Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  this.startActivity(intent);                     
            } 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How to ignore beacon for a while

Comment: @ManishButola on `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` save the `beconid` and check it. I will update my answer with code

Comment: @ManishButola check if this helps. If not you can try and uncomment `mRegionBootstrap.disable();` to stop scanning and see if the problem continues.

Comment: your code stop launching an activity again and again  for a time being but when i press back button from that  Activity the whole application stop.

Comment: i would have to see the error to know why if crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple way to solve this is to store boolean flags like this:

```
private Boolean firstActivityLaunched = false;
private Boolean secondActivityLaunched = false;
```

Then change your code to use these:

```
@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

    //mRegionBootstrap.disable();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (beacons.size() > 0) {        
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {          
            String beconid=beacon.toString();               

            if(beacon.getDistance()<1 && beconid.equals("id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 20155 id3: 28577") && !firstActivityLaunched)
            {
                firstActivityLaunched = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
                // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  this.startActivity(intent);                     
            } 

            if(beacon.getDistance()<1 && beconid.equals("id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 8128 id3: 59794") && !secondActivityLaunched)
            {
                secondActivityLaunched = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  this.startActivity(intent);                     
            } 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing but when i press back button from activity then my application get halt.

Comment: Please post a stack trace

Comment: I am unable to get back from activity into my application i means the application get hang                                                                                 My locat output is as follow :04-10 18:09:48.626: D/BluetoothAdapter(19046): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=8
04-10 18:09:49.756: D/BluetoothAdapter(19046): stopLeScan()
04-10 18:09:49.776: D/BluetoothAdapter(19046): startLeScan(): null

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is not so complicated problem,

> It can be solved in 2 steps:
>   1. set a boolean in consistent memory when an activity is fired
>   2. reset boolean in consistent memory when an main activity is restarted

1. To set in consistent memory [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Before you start activity1

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(sp.getBoolean("activity1",false)==false){
    sp.edit().putBoolean ("activity1", true).commit();
    startActivity(activity1);
}
```

2. To reset consistent memory

add this in your `onCreate` in your mainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    sp.edit().putBoolean ("activity1", false).commit();
    super.onResume();
}
```

You can create `SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);` as global variable if needed